# what is LVM _tmeta _tdata in lsblk

Tags: lvm, proxmox

I've installed proxmox (sda) and did some LVM on another disks than proxmox was installed on (sdc, sdd). Now my setups is following:

```
root@pve:~# lsblk
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0    32G  0 disk
├─sda1                    8:1    0  1007K  0 part
├─sda2                    8:2    0   512M  0 part
└─sda3                    8:3    0  31.5G  0 part
  ├─pve-swap            253:4    0   3.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─pve-root            253:5    0   7.8G  0 lvm  /
  ├─pve-data_tmeta      253:6    0     1G  0 lvm
  │ └─pve-data          253:8    0    14G  0 lvm
  └─pve-data_tdata      253:7    0    14G  0 lvm
    └─pve-data          253:8    0    14G  0 lvm
sdb                       8:16   0     8G  0 disk
sdc                       8:32   0     4G  0 disk
├─LVMVolGroup-projects  253:0    0     2G  0 lvm
├─LVMVolGroup-www       253:1    0     1G  0 lvm
└─LVMVolGroup-workspace 253:3    0     2G  0 lvm
sdd                       8:48   0     4G  0 disk
├─LVMVolGroup-db        253:2    0     3G  0 lvm
└─LVMVolGroup-workspace 253:3    0     2G  0 lvm
sr0                      11:0    1 862.6M  0 rom

root@pve:~# ls -la /dev/mapper/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     240 Jan 17 22:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root    4460 Jan 17 22:05 ..
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 Jan 17 22:05 control
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jan 17 22:05 LVMVolGroup-db -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jan 17 22:05 LVMVolGroup-projects -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jan 17 22:05 LVMVolGroup-workspace -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jan 17 22:05 LVMVolGroup-www -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jan 17 22:05 pve-data -> ../dm-8
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jan 17 22:05 pve-data_tdata -> ../dm-7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jan 17 22:05 pve-data_tmeta -> ../dm-6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jan 17 22:05 pve-root -> ../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Jan 17 22:05 pve-swap -> ../dm-4
```

1. What is `_tmeta` & `_tdata` is it some kind of LV or what?
2. What is `pve-data`?
3. Which commands can be used to show more info about `pve-data` `_tmeta` `_tdata` ? I've tried stadard LVM commands such as: `pvs lvs vgs pvdisplay vgdisplay lvdisplay` with no luck.
4. What commands was used to create structure like this?
5. Most importantly: what is it good for and why it was created?

Answer (score 2):

`pve-data` is a logical volume called `data` in a volume group called `pve`, this is a [standard proxmox setup with LVM](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(LVM)). `data` LV is a thin pool (see [this article](https://storageapis.wordpress.com/2016/06/24/lvm-thin-provisioning/) explaining thin provisioning or `man lvmthin`) used for virtualization (backing storage for VMs is allocated as new thin logical volumes instead of files stored somewhere in `/var`). The thin pool itself consists of two "parts" -- data and metadata internal logical volumes, these are the `_tmeta` (thin pool metadata) and `_tdata` (thin pool data) LVs you see in `lsblk`. `lvs` command by default doesn't show internal lvs, you need to use `lvs -a` to display all logical volumes including the internal ones. Thin pools are created the same way "normal" LVs are, using `lvcreate` just with `-T` or `--type thin-pool`.